# How to get ListBox to load after selecting ComboBox value?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, combobox, listbox

Working in VS 2012, WinForms, C#...

I have a ListBox I would like to populate depending upon the value selected in a ComboBox. I've tested my SQL Query and it works, but I'm getting a weird problem where, when I run my routines, my ComboBox comes up empty, as well as my ListBox. When I comment out the code in my `cb_Session_SelectedValueChanged` routine, my CB and LB load just fine, but when it's not commented out is when my LB and CB end up blank.

This is what I have:

```
private void cb_Session_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listbox_Sessions.Visible = true;
    LoadSessionListbox();
}

private void LoadSessionListbox()
{
    int tempID = Convert.ToInt32(cb_Session.SelectedValue);
    // Code here to load listbox, which works without above routine.
}
```

Am I missing something? Why are my CB and LB blank with that first routine added?

[EDIT]:

I put the routines which were in SelectedValueChanged in a MouseClick event and it works, but not when I want it to... You have to click a couple times to get it to re-load with the correct ID. I feel like I'm getting closer, but still not the right event.

Comment: `cb_Session_SelectedValueChanged` is probably being called when your form is initialized and `cb_Session.SelectedValue` is probably `null` at that point. Since `cb_Session.SelectvedValue` is null, that value is being loaded into your `ListBox`. Can you post more code so we can see exactly what is happening?

Comment: @IanO'Brien I can, I'm just not sure what code to post. I'm at the point where I'm drowning in code on this form...

Comment: Have you got events raised by the listbox that impact the combobox? The coude you posted seems fine but it is not enough. How and when is CB filled?

Comment: CB is filled in the public ThisForm() {} routine. (Very beginning) I have all my CB and LB routines in there.

Comment: If you aren't certain what code to post, post the code that revolves around the `combobox`, `listbox` and the `eventhandlers` that call them.

Comment: Can you try placing a breakpoint on the line `int tempID = Convert.ToInt32(cb_Session.SelectedValue);` and running your code to see what `cb_Session.SelectedValue` is?

Comment: Can you show where you are initializing your combo box or binding it?

Comment: @IanO'Brien cb_Session.SelectedValue is, in fact, 0 when my LoadSessionListbox() routine hits the int tempID part. Is there a better event to use rather than SelectedValueChanged for my ComboBox that won't run until the value is *actually* changed?

Comment: @DJBurb Where as in where in code? Or the routine that populates my CB?

Comment: Both, if possible.  It helps to see where the combobox gets populated.  Sometimes, if the population is placed in the wrong place, the window will load before the combobox has a chance to populate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!!

I ended up adding a simple if statement to my SelectedValueChanged routine, and it fixed everything!

```
private void cb_Sessions_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox_Sessions.Visible = true;

    if (cb_Sessions.SelectedValue != null)
        LoadSessionListbox();
}
```

Works perfectly now.

Comment: Oh.  I figured the null didn't need to be checked because the event was being fired.  So I assumed that SelectedValue wouldn't be null.  That's why I edited. Bah well *shrug*

Comment: @DJBurb I'm just happy I got it working. :) You all helped a lot getting me to the point I needed.

Comment: @spajce I have.. Why do you say that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void cb_Session_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(cb_Session.SelectedValue>-1)
   {
    listbox_Sessions.Visible = true;
    LoadSessionListbox();
   }

}
```

Comment: actually the cb_Session.SelectedValue!=null is not needed, I'll edit

Answer (score 0):

Try in `SelectedIndexChanged Event` and follow

```
private void cb_Session_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cb_Session.SelectedValue == null) return;
    if (cb_Session.SelectedIndex == -1) return;
    listbox_Sessions.Visible = true;
    LoadSessionListbox((int)cb_Session.SelectedValue);
}

private void LoadSessionListbox(int selectedValue)
{
   //TODO: Do stuff
}
```